Teradata SQL using recursive logic in SQL
I am using Teradata and there is a scenario which I am not sure how to achieve it using sql query. I have a table with data as given below. The table is grouped based on the columns GP,Key1,Key2 and Key3. Now my requirement is that, I need to populate the start date from the column process date, for few of the ID.




GP
ID
start date
process date
Key1
key2
key3




W1
W003
Current_Date
2023-04-24
1asd
345
456


W1
W004

2024-08-20
1asd
345
456


W1
W005

2024-08-21
1asd
345
456


W1
W0010

2024-08-22
1asd
345
456


W1
W0120

2024-08-23
1asd
345
456


W1
W0015

2024-08-24
1asd
345
456


W1
W0016

2024-08-25
1asd
345
456


W2
W234
Current_Date
2021-05-27
2def
111
222


W2
W345

2022-03-21
2def
111
222


W2
W456

2023-03-21
2def
111
222



Now the case here is, in the column ID for the value W004 and W005, I need to populate start date as process date from W003.
Similar way  in the column ID for the value W0010,W0120,W0015 and W0016 , I need to populate start date as process date from W005
When it comes to the ID W345 and W456, the start date needs to populated with W234 process start date.
Result table should look as below

I know we can do join with the same table multiple time and try to achieve this, but just thinking is there anyway we can achieve it using a single query. Please note that the connection to IDs which need to populated for start date and from ID where we take the value wont change. For ex. W004 and W005 always take the value from W003 , like that W0010,W0120,W0015 and W0016 always take value from W005

How do we know how ID's belong to a group? Will no new ID's ever show up in your table?

The assignment of values from process date to start date will always happen between within a group of IDs only. There wont be new IDs showing up

Define group of ID's.

Group of IDs are those values mentioned in the column ID, and its grouped by the columns GP,Key1,Key2 and Key3

So why doesn't W0010 have start date as process date from W003?

so not all records in the group have that requirement, only those record IDs which are mentioned needs this and it wont chnage

Sounds like a variation of conditional aggregation using Windowed Aggregates:
case
  when id in ('W004', 'W005') 
    then max(case when id = 'W003' then process_date end) over (partition by GP)
  when id in ('W0010', 'W0120', 'W0015', 'W0016') 
    then max(case when id = 'W005' then process_date end) over (partition by GP)
  else current_date
end

